# showing a sequence of sequences converges

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have an infinite sequence of finite $n$-tuples with:

$$f_1 = (a_{11},\space a_{12},\space ... , \space a_{1n})$$
$$f_2 = (a_{21},\space a_{22}, \space ... ,\space a_{2n})$$
$$f_3 = (a_{31}, \space a_{32}, \space ... , \space a_{3n})$$
$$\vdots \qquad \qquad  \qquad \vdots$$

Further suppose that the "$k^{th}$ vertical sequence" i.e. the sequence formed by the $k^{th}$ element of each sequence i.e.  $(a_{1k}, \space a_{2k}, \space a_{3k}, ... )$ converges to some real number $a_k$, and that this is true for all the "vertical" sequences meaning for all integers $k$ with $1 \leq k\leq n.$

Then, we can show that under the following metric $$ d((b_1, b_2,...), (c_1, c_2, ...)) = \sup_k \space\{|b_j - c_j|\}$$ the sequence of $n$-tuples $f_1, f_2, ...$ converges to $ f = (a_1, a_2, ...)$:

Since the sequence $(a_{1k}, \space a_{2k}, \space a_{3k}, ... )$ converges to $a_k$, given $\epsilon > 0 ,$ there exists a positive integer $N_k$ such that for all $m \geq N_k$
$$|a_{mk} - a_k| < \epsilon$$

Let $N = \max\{N_1, N_2, ... N_n\}$.

Then, given $\epsilon > 0$, for all $m \geq N$, for **all** $\textbf{k} \in \{1, 2, ..., n\}$ $$|a_{mk} - a_k| < \epsilon $$

Therefore,
$$\sup_k \space \{|a_{mk} - a_k|\} <\epsilon$$

Thus, for all $k \geq N$,
$$d(f_k, f) < \epsilon$$

So $\{f_k \}$ converges to $f$.

**Question:** My question is suppose instead of finite $n$-tuples, we have each $f_k$ is an infinite sequence, can this proof be modified to show that the $f_k$ converge to $f$?

i.e. suppose we have an infinite sequence of infinite sequences with:

$$f_1 = (a_{11},\space a_{12},\space ... )$$
$$f_2 = (a_{21},\space a_{22}, \space ... )$$
$$f_3 = (a_{31}, \space a_{32}, \space ... )$$
$$\vdots \qquad \qquad  \qquad \vdots$$

It seems like there is trouble because we can't say "let $N = \max \{N_1, N_2, ...\}$" since this will be an infinite set.

How can we fix this? Or is the statement not true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterexample: With
$$
 f_1 = (1, 1, 1, 1, \ldots) \\
 f_2 = (0, 1, 1, 1, \ldots) \\
 f_3 = (0, 0, 1, 1, \ldots) \\
 f_4 = (0, 0, 0, 1, \ldots) \\
\vdots
$$
you have “column-wise” convergence to
$$
 f_0 = (0, 0, 0, 0, \ldots) \\
$$
but
$$
d(f_j, f_0) = \sup_k |f_{jk} - f_{0k}| = 1 
$$
does not converge to zero.

*Remark:* With a different metric such as
$$d(f, g)=\sum^\infty_{n=k}\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{|f_k-g_k|}{1+|f_k-g_k|}
$$
convergence in each component is equivalent to convergence with respect to $d$, see for example [Convergence with respect to $d_1(x,y)=\sum^\infty_{i=1}\frac{1}{2^i}\frac{|x_i-y_i|}{1+|x_i-y_i|}$ is equivalent to pointwise convergence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3045421/convergence-with-respect-to-d-1x-y-sum-infty-i-1-frac12i-fracx-i-y).